# How to fetch a particular column value which has same values in other columns of a table

Tags: sql-server

Am have a following data:
[image]

As there are 3 different results for Student_ID 111. I need a query to fetch the row which has the result as 'pass' as well fetch the row with student_ID 112 which as a result as Fail.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

**I would do it with row_number and partition by**

```
create table #t(student_id int, name varchar(50), result varchar(50))
insert into #t values 
(111,'Jhon','Pass'),
(111,'Jhon','Absent'),
(111,'Jhon','Fail'),
(112,'Max','Fail');

WITH filterQuery as(
    select 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY student_id ORDER BY CASE result
                                                            WHEN 'Pass' THEN 0
                                                            WHEN 'Fail' THEN 1
                                                            WHEN 'Absent' THEN 2
                                                        END ASC) 
      AS Row , 
    * from #t
)
select student_id, name, result from filterQuery where Row = 1

DROP Table #t
```

[image: Result]

But the database design is not really good

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below Query:

```
select * from Student where Result = 'Pass' Or (Student_ID = 112 And Result = 'Fail')
```

Comment: the data mentioned is just a sample data there are many records.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..

```
SELECT * FROM `tblname` WHERE Result = 'Pass' OR Result = 'Fail'
```